# Symfony 4.4 metadata_cache_driver configuration key deprecation notice

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-4.4

Since I've upgraded Symfony from 4.4.15 to 4.4.16 I've got following deprecation notice:

> The "metadata_cache_driver" configuration key is deprecated. PHP Array
> cache is now automatically registered when %kernel.debug% is false.

This is strange as the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers) don't say anything about this deprecation except of this text:

> Deprecated since version 4.4:All the Doctrine caching types are
> deprecated since Symfony 4.4 and won’t be available in Symfony 5.0 and
> higher. Replace them with either type: service or type: pool and use
> any of the cache pools/services defined with Symfony Cache.

But I'm using caching type pool or service. My configuration looks like this:

```
doctrine:  
    orm:  
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool  

framework:
    cache:
        default_memcached_provider: 'memcached://localhost:11211'
        pools:
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.memcached
                public: false
                default_lifetime: 86400
```

I even tried to config the cache as a service like this which gives me the same deprecation notice:

```
doctrine:
    orm:    
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider

services:
    doctrine.system_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
    cache:
        default_memcached_provider: 'memcached://localhost:11211'
        pools:
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.memcached
                public: false
                default_lifetime: 86400
```

Any ideas how to get rid of the deprecation notice?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question, don't get the downvote either. Here is the pull request that added the deprecation notice: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/1196. That might give some information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the deprecation was reverted: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/1255

So please make sure to keep the `metadata_cache_driver` config for your production environments when upgrading to DoctrineBundle 2.2.1.

EDIT: **The feature was released again with version 2.3.0 of DoctrineBundle**. So the `metadata_cache_driver` config can safely be removed for prod environments when using this version.

Comment: Do you know if it's save to remove the metadata_cache_driver entry or is the removal necessary at all on PROD? Getting following deprecation notice on DEV: "The "metadata_cache_driver" configuration key is deprecated. PHP Array cache is now automatically registered when %kernel.debug% is false"

Comment: @ninsky indeed when using version 2.3.0 you can remove the config option as the feature was released again. I updated my comment above.

Answer (score 4):

As of DoctrineBundle 2.2.0 you can safely remove `metadata_cache_driver` from your configuration. There is no replacement; just delete it.

The [pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/1196) that introduced this deprecation notice gives some explanation: "Change is needed because defining own metadata_cache_driver is useless from now on."

Doctrine now uses `PhpArrayAdapter` in production environment.